# Prevent duplicate entries in array in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

User schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({

name:           { type: String, required:true },
email:          { type: String, required:true, lowercase: true , index : { unique: true } },
password :      { type: String, required:true , select:true },
blog_bookmarks: [{ type: String }]

});
```

API to add values to `blog_bookmarks` for a particular user

```
api.post('/add_bookmark_blog', function(req, res){

 User.findOne({_id: req.query.user_id}, function(err, user){
    if(err)
    {
        res.json(err)
    }
    else{
        var blogid = req.body.blog_id;   
        user.find({ blog_bookmarks : blogid}, function(res1, result){
            if(res1){
                user.blog_bookmarks.push(blogid);
                user.save(function(err) {
                    if(err){
                            res.json('ERROR at adding bookmark')
                        }
                    else {
                            res.json('bookmark for blog added')
                        }
                })
            }
            else{
                res.json('Already bookmarked')
            }  
        });
    }
    })
});
```

I want to add `blog_id` to `blog_bookmarks` array only if it doesn't exist, I don't want multiple entries.

Currently, `user.find()` gives console error

> user.find() is not a function

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For avoiding duplicate values in your `blog_bookmarks`, use the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator.

```
User.update({_id: req.query.user_id}, {$addToSet: {blog_bookmarks: blogid}})
```

Your `user.find()` gives you probably an error because it should be `User.find()` with a capital U at the beginning.